# Strict type alias in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have a recursive function taking 3 integers, each having a different meaning, e.g.

```haskell
func :: Int -> Int -> Int -> SomeType1 -> SomeType2
```

What I want is to prevent myself from mistyping the order of the arguments like this (somewhere in the func implementation):

```haskell
func a b c t = f b a c ( someProcessing t )
```

The easiest way I've come up with is to define type aliases like

```haskell
type FuncFirstArg = Int
type FuncSecondArg = Int
type FuncThirdArg = Int
```

And change `func` signature:

```haskell
func :: FuncFirstArg -> FuncSecondArg -> FuncThirdArg -> SomeType1 -> SomeType2
```

But it seems like this approach doesn't work as I intended. Why does Haskell still allow me to pass `FuncSecondArg` as a first argument and so on. Is there a way to do what I want without declaring datatypes?

Comment: The whole point of `type` is that you're just giving an alias name to the same type. It means that you don't need to explicitly wrap anything, but of course it also means that there is no additional type safety. If that's what you want, then use a `newtype`.

Comment: In addition to @leftaroundabout's comment, see this: https://wiki.haskell.org/Type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`type` in Haskell is a rename of an existing type. Just like `String` and `[Char]` are fully exchangeable, so are `FuncFirstArg` and `Int`, and by transition `FuncSecondArg` as well.

The most normal solution is to use a `newtype` which was introduced exactly for the purpose of what you try to achieve. For convenience, it is good to declare it as a record:

```
newtype FuncFirstArg = FuncFirstArg {unFuncFirstArg :: Int}
```

Note that `newtype` is entirely reduced during compilation time, so it has no overhead on the runtime.

---

However, if you have many arguments like in your example, a common strategy is to create a dedicated type for all of the parameters supplied to the function:

```
data FuncArgs = FuncArgs
  { funcA :: Int
  , funcB :: Int
  , funcC :: Int
  , funcT :: Sometype1
  }

f :: FuncArgs -> Sometype2
```

Yes, it has some bad impact on currying and partial application, but in many cases you can deal with it by providing predefined argument packs or even uncurry the function:

```
defaultArgs :: Sometype1 -> FuncArgs
defaultArgs t = FuncArgs {a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, t = t}

fUnc :: Int -> Int -> Int -> SomeType1 -> SomeType2
fUnc a b c t = f $ FuncArgs a b c t
```

### Conclusion

For the typechecker to distinguish types, the types have to be actually different. You can't skip defining new types, therefore.